# Webpack fails to compile when bootstrap is added

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Im trying to get the bootstrap components on my react app to work .
I have followed the guides https://dzone.com/articles/adding-react-bootstrap-to-a-react-app and https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/301 .

When I import the `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` into my index.js. I get this error on webpack .
[image]

My `webpack.config.js` is as follows .

```
     module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to install and configure css-loader and style-loader

Answer (score 1):

You need `style-loader` and `css-loader` to work with css files.

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ],
  },
...
```

> Note: That config is for Webpack 2+.

**For Webpack 1:**

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
    ]
  },
...
```

Simply install `style-loader` and `css-loader`.

`npm i css-loader style-loader -S`

Comment: Hi , did the npm install as you suggested and added rules. Still get the error . I am using webpack 1.15.0 though .

Comment: I got bootstrap to load via react-bootstrap . For some reason the above stated methods are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same issue with bootstrap and webpack, but importing it directly into my css file solved this issue.

Hope it helps someone.

```js
/*package.json*/
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "4.3.1"
},
```

```css
/*css|scss file*/

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```